# Обратимый xor на php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Нужна ваша помощь в решении одной задачки.
Есть три переменные:

> $a = 16431130;
>   $b = 15318085;
>   $c = 8860504;
>   $result = $a ^ $b ^ c;

В конце известно 2 значения, переменная $result и переменная $c. Скажите, как из этих 2 переменных получить переменные $a и $b. Как лучше изменить
$result = $a ^ $b ^ c;
чтобы получить нужный результат?

Comment: Очевидно никак не получить.

Comment: вообще без вариантов?

Comment: a=1, b=2, c=3, r=0 или a=0, b=3, c=3, r=0. Вы знаете только c и r. Какой из вариантов вы хотите получить?

Comment: `$a = rand(); $b = $a ^ $c ^ $result;`

Comment: Советую почитать про стойкость [гаммирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему вы хотите взломать [Шифр Вернама](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0).
Он используется военными для передачи сверх секретной информации и без знания ключа его не взломать. Если получится - напишите сюда - вы привнесете неоценимый вклад в криптографию.
В вашем случае можно лишь получить результат $a ^ $b вот так:

```
function myXor($c,$result){
   return $result^$c;
}
```

Comment: возможно можно обойтись без xor? может есть какие-то формулы, чтобы можно було обратить результат из 3 переменных $a,$b,$c?

Comment: уважаемый user235655 результатом $a ^ $b может выступать экспоненциальное количество ответов - поясню что имею ввиду вы получили 0 под это подходит 1 и 1, а также 0 и 0;;; вы получили 1 под это подходит 0 и 1, а также подходит 1 и 0;;; вы получили 01 под это подходит 01 и 00, а также 10 и 11, а также 11 и 10... Если вы хотите получить рандомно 2 любых числа $а и $b - то перепишите вопрос.Если вы хотите узнать количество подходящих под $a и $b количество вариантов , то измените вопрос. В противном случае вам закрыть этот вопрос - ответ на него дан и доказан.

Answer (score 1):

> Как лучше изменить...

Можно хранить a и b в разных битах.

```
$result = ($a << 32 | $b) ^ $c;
```

Вот код:

```
$a = 12345;
$b = 65432;
$c = 723648723;
$res = ($a << 32 | $b) ^ $c;

$ab = $res ^ $c;
$b = ($res ^ $c) % (1 << 32) | 0;
$a = ($res ^ $c) / (1 << 32) | 0;

var_dump([$a, $b]);
```

Результат:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(12345)
  [1]=>
  int(65432)
}
```

К сожалению, при недостаточно большом `$c` значение `$a` будет представлено в открытом виде. Необходимо выбирать `$c`, как случайное 64битное число. `$a` и `$b` в свою очередь, ограничены 32битным диапазоном.